# Libgdx: Can I draw text onto screen by reading from a text file?

Tags: libgdx, draw

I would like my programme to be able to draw fonts through reading from a text file (e.g. reading a row from a file), does anyone know a way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can draw text onto screen by reading from text file.

Here is test case: 
I've two file, one is `.txt` and another one is `.json`.

[image]

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont bitmapFont;
    String txtFileString;
    String jsonString;
    JsonValue jsonValue;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        bitmapFont=new BitmapFont();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        txtFileString = Gdx.files.internal("file.txt").readString();
        jsonString=Gdx.files.internal("file.json").readString();

        JsonReader jsonReader= new JsonReader();
        jsonValue=jsonReader.parse(Gdx.files.internal("file.json"));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        bitmapFont.draw(batch, txtFileString,10,380);
        bitmapFont.draw(batch, jsonString,10,300);
        bitmapFont.draw(batch,jsonValue.get("framework").asString(),10,180);
        bitmapFont.draw(batch,jsonValue.get("language").asString(),10,160);

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        bitmapFont.dispose();
    }
}
```

My expected output :

[image]